# Adding longtable to \listoftables

Tags: table-of-contents, longtable

How to add a longtable into a listoftables, please ?

I've filled my longtable, but, the listoftables still empty. How to deal this please ?

The code tht I've used :

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
B & A. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\[-7pt]  
\caption[]{Description textuelle du cas d'utilisation \og Rechercher application métier \fg.}
\label{tbl:desc_txt_rech_appmetier}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

Now that the answer has been edited, the problem is clear. If you use an empty optional argument for `\caption`, then no entry is produced in the list. Don't use the optional argument empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
B & A. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\[-7pt]  
\caption{Description textuelle du cas d'utilisation \og Rechercher application métier \fg.}
\label{tbl:desc_txt_rech_appmetier}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer (before the edit to the question)

Simply use `\caption` and process the document twice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{longtable}{c}
\caption{a longtable} \\
\hline
text \\
text \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using one `\caption` before `\endfirsthead` and another one before `\endhead` you can even have a caption on the first page and another one for the other pages spanned by the table (notice the empty optional argument in the second `\caption` to prevent a duplicated entry in the list of tables):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{longtable}{c}
\caption{a longtable}
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{a longtable (Continued)}
\endhead
\hline
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
text \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please look my edit. Actually, I'm using `caption` but I cannot see any entry into my listoftables. Can you please explain me why ? I'm using report as type of document.

Comment: @user44584 Remove the optional argument. Use `\caption{text}` and not `\caption[]{text}`